# Camunda: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm trying the Camunda Enterprise today and notice the issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2993)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2432)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:908)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
    at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.parkway.camunda.config.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:25)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    ...
```

Not sure this one is a bug or not ? 
Only happen on

```
Spring-Boot:  (v2.2.1.RELEASE)
Camunda BPM: (v7.12.0-ee)
Camunda BPM Spring Boot Starter: (v3.4.0)
```

I've tried with the same set of code and it's working fine on

```
Spring-Boot:  (v2.2.1.RELEASE)
Camunda BPM: (v7.10.0)
Camunda BPM Spring Boot Starter: (v3.2.0)
```

Can someone help me to check ? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

After search on the Internet for a day, I finally found the issue.

**Root cause:** because I'm calling REST API outside of Camunda website without turn on the Authentication mechanism and also using /api/abc/do-something

Ref: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/rest/overview/authentication/

> The REST API ships with an implementation of HTTP Basic Authentication. By default it is switched off.
>
> Any request that does not address a specific engine (i.e., it is not of the form /engine/{name}/...) will be authenticated against the default engine.

Solution:

1. Change API path: `from /api/abc/do-something -> /engine/api/abc/do-something`
2. Switch on the Authentication by adding this configuration class (if you are using Spring Boot)

```
@Configuration
public class CamundaSecurityFilter {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean processEngineAuthenticationFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setName("camunda-auth");
        registration.setFilter(getProcessEngineAuthenticationFilter());
        registration.addInitParameter("authentication-provider",
                "org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.security.auth.impl.HttpBasicAuthenticationProvider");
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter getProcessEngineAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new ProcessEngineAuthenticationFilter();
    }
}
```

Thanks to this guys: https://forum.camunda.org/t/turn-on-basic-http-authentication-for-rest-api-in-spring-boot/3431